# Codeigniter base url didn't recognized in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I have an ajax request in my CI application ,here is my cstom.js file for that purpose.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var base_url='<?php echo base_url();?>';
   $('#add-ct').click(function(){      
      $.ajax({
          url:base_url+'stockmanagement/add_category',
          data:{category:$('#category').val()},
          success:function(data){
              alert(data);
          },
          error:function(err){
              alert('error'+err);
          }
      });
   });
});
```

But the `base_url` didn't recolonized, when i check the debug console the `base_url` is printed as the same as the source code like this way.

```
var base_url='<?php echo base_url(); ?>';
```

**UPDATE**

my javascript file is included in a view file

```
<?php if($page=='add-category'){ echo '<script src="'.base_url().'/assets/js/custom.js"></script>'; }?>
```

Comment: what is the file extension of your file?

Comment: its a js file custom.js

Comment: how you expect that in a js file php will work?

Comment: the javascript should be located in your view file with the `.php` extension for it to recognize php code.

Comment: where is this javascript located? provide the name of the file and the location of the file.

Comment: Did you autoload url helper?

Comment: Yes url helper is loaded,

Comment: @codeGodie i've updated my question

Comment: I see.. did you setup your `base_url` in `application/config/config.php`?

Comment: Yes it is setuped in config.php

Comment: Wait.. so you are using `<?php ?>` tags inside `custom.js`?

Comment: yes the script is loaded based on a condtion

Comment: it doesnt matter how or where the script loads. any file without the `.php` extension will not read PHP code. You need to set the base_url in your html `head` like how @SanyaZahid showed in her answer below. have you tried that yet?

Comment: but the custom.js file is loaded in a file named footer.php

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to run PHP code inside a JS file. This will not work as PHP code can only run inside files named with a `.php` extension.

To fix this, you have to set a global variable in Javascript to hold the value of your base_url

so if you want to include a JS file you should first define the variable like in the following example:

**index.php**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- SET GLOBAL BASE URL -->
    <script>var base_url = '<?php echo base_url() ?>';</script>
    <script src="/assets/js/custom.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

**custom.js**

```
//now we can reference the base_url
alert(base_url+"some/other");
```

Answer (score 2):

Declare var base_url in your header file

```
<script>
var base_url = "<?php echo base_url();?>";
</script>
```

Comment: Nop its again printed the same

Answer (score 1):

In the template, I put this :

```
<script>
  var base_url = "<?= base_url(); ?>";
</script>
<script src="<?= base_url('assets/js/main.js'); ?>">
```

And then in then main.js like this :

```
function logout(){
    var element = document.getElementById("lobtn");
    location.href = base_url+"user/logout";
}
```

It will send you to "yoursite.com/user/logout"...

Edit : The "lobtn" is an ID from your Logout Button...

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo base_url();?>
```

The PHP code does not execute in js file. You have to declare
`var base_url = "<?php echo base_url();?>";` in a PHP file such as template file as a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    var base_url = "<?php echo base_url();?>";
</script>
```

You can do one thing copy above code and paste it to your header file