# How to dynamic a url with codeigniter base_url() inside js file

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, url, base-url

I want to load a url with dynamically inside js file. i used below code inside the head.js file but it's not getting the url. if i use statically then it works nicely. I can't find my problem.

```
head.js(<?php echo base_url(); ?>"assets/js/newsticker/jquery.newsTicker.js", function() {
    var nt_title = $('#nt-title').newsTicker({
        row_height: 18,
        max_rows: 1,
        duration: 5000,
        pauseOnHover: 0
    });
});
```

Comment: You can use php only in .php file not in .js file . What is your Base url and what url you get  by `/` + `assets/`

Comment: if the filename is `head.js` this would not work, you have to name your file `head.php`

Comment: if i rename head.js file as head.php then will it be worked for js code???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36051588/codeigniter-base-url-didnt-recongnized-in-javascript

Comment: @user7149801 try as below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't use `<?php echo base_url(); ?>` on JavaScript file.

If you want to get the url dynamically, you can use `window.location.origin`

```
var url = window.location.origin;
```

> Variable `url` will print like `base_url` : https://stackoverflow.com
>
> Subdomain will print like : https://subdomain.stackoverflow.com

So, just changes your `<?php echo base_url(); ?>` into `url+` and add `/` before assets, like :

```
head.js(url+"/assets/js/newsticker/jquery.newsTicker.js", function() {
    var nt_title = $('#nt-title').newsTicker({
        row_height: 18,
        max_rows: 1,
        duration: 5000,
        pauseOnHover: 0
    });
});
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get `base_url()` in pure JS file.Following may be a right way...

1.In html (PHP) create a input field of hidden type with value base_url.As

```
<input type="hidden" id="url" value="<?php echo base_url();?>">
```

2.Then in your Pure JS file such as `head.js`.Get base_url as below.

```
<script>
var base_url = $("#url").val();//it gives base_url
head.js(base_url+"assets/js/newsticker/jquery.newsTicker.js", function() {
    var nt_title = $('#nt-title').newsTicker({
        row_height: 18,
        max_rows: 1,
        duration: 5000,
        pauseOnHover: 0
    });
});
</script>
```

**NOTE**: In codeigniter don't forget to load `url` helper for use of `base_url()`.